# Are there any issues with sparsely populated partitioned tables

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

The partitioning strategy used by a third party product results in a fairly sparse distribution of data.
i.e. of our ~900 partitions only ~300 have data. The way this works it will only become more sparse over time.
Is there any value in merging consecutive empty partitions (I can guarantee there will be no inserts into them) or is this a waste of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each partition is essentially a separate table, so there is some cost involved in query optimization, statistics, and metadata management.  So if the third-party product supports you removing partition boundary points they created, I would probably do it.

See

> The new, higher limit of 15,000 partitions affects memory, partitioned
>   index operations, DBCC commands, and queries. This section describes
>   the performance implications of increasing the number of partitions
>   above 1,000 and provides workarounds as needed.

[Partitioned Tables and Indexes - Performance Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#performance-guidelines)